# How can i pass parameter to this method

Tags: c#

This is the method:

```
getUsersList(ref List<RealBioSDKUser> userList, 
             int groupId = -1, 
             [DateTimeConstant(0), Optional] DateTime fromDate)
```

When I pass the parameters like this :

```
List<RealBioSDKUser> tempUserList=new List<RealBioSDKUser>();
BioClient.getUsersList(ref tempUserList,0, "1900-01-01");
```

is shows this error:

> the best overloaded method match for collections.generic.list like this.

Comment: You are passing a `string` for a `DateTime` parameter. Use `DateTime.Parse` instead, or omit the argument if you don't need it.

Comment: FYI: a more "obvious" method signature here would be `List<RealBioSDKUser> GetUsersList(int groupId = -1, DateTime fromDate = default(DateTime))` - it might not be your API to change, of course - although note that this gives a different default date - IMO a more idiomatic one

Answer (score 4):

Because `"1900-01-01"` is a string, not a `DateTime`.  Pass a `DateTime` object instead:

```
BioClient.getUsersList(ref tempUserList,0, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

When invoking, provide `DateTime` (i.e. `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)`) instance, not `String` (`"1900-01-01"`) one:

```
getUsersList(ref List<RealBioSDKUser> userList, 
             int groupId = -1, 
            [DateTimeConstant(0), Optional] DateTime fromDate) // <- DateTime


... 

List<RealBioSDKUser> tempUserList = new List<RealBioSDKUser>();

BioClient.getUsersList(ref tempUserList, 0, new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)); // <- DateTime
```